# ¿Se puede condicionar un evento change de un select en javascript o query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, condiciones, select, eventos

Les comento, necesito agarrar el atributo no_precio de una opción de mi select con el id: nuevoIdCliente, comparto código:

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="nuevoIdCliente" name="nuevoIdCliente">
<option no_precio="1" value="Pedro">Pedro</option>
<option no_precio="2" value="Marco">Marco</option>
<option no_precio="2" value="Erik">Erik</option>
</select>
```

Como pueden ver mi select tiene a Pedro como opción por default, por lo que he logrado agarrar el atributo no_precio de esa opción por default, pero al momento de cambiar de opción no consigo obtener el atributo de esa otra opción, comparto mi código javascript

```
if($("nuevoIdCliente").change()){
    var no_precio = $("#nuevoIdCliente>option:selected").attr("no_precio");
            alert(no_precio);
    }else{
            var no_precio = $("#nuevoIdCliente>option:selected").attr("no_precio");
            alert(no_precio);
    }
```

Aqui lo que me funciona es el else ya que como dije, ya logre obtener el atributo de la opción por default, pero no logro obtener el valor de los demás una vez cambio de opción.

Espero me puedan ayudar o corregirme, igual espero haberme dado a explicar

Y aquí les dejo de nuevo mi código con el javascript para ejecutarlo.

```js
    if($("#nuevoIdCliente").change()){
        var no_precio = $("#nuevoIdCliente>option:selected").attr("no_precio");
                alert(no_precio);
        }else{
                var no_precio = $("#nuevoIdCliente>option:selected").attr("no_precio");
                alert(no_precio);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select2" id="nuevoIdCliente" name="nuevoIdCliente">
    <option no_precio="1" value="Pedro">Pedro</option>
    <option no_precio="2" value="Marco">Marco</option>
    <option no_precio="2" value="Erik">Erik</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

yo estuve trabajando en algo parecido y lo que use fue el value:
en vez de:

```
var no_precio = $("#nuevoIdCliente>option:selected").attr("no_precio");
            alert(no_precio);
```

Probaste con esto?:

`var no_precio = document.getElementById("nuevoIdCliente").value;`

Comment: Hola, si lo que pasa es que yo no quiero agarrar el value, porque en el value me agarra los nombres y yo no quiero los nombres, quiero el número de precio del nombre que escoja, ya que ese value si lo voy a usar, pero igual necesito usar el numero de precio

Answer (score 0):

Diría que tienes problemas de concepto de algunas cosas. A saber:

1. El problema es justamente el condicional que has puesto, que no tiene mucho sentido cuando estás monitorizando eventos, y además no lo estás dejando a la escucha sino que tan solo lo ejecutas una sola vez durante la carga del script.
2. Tal como tienes ahora los option, no hay ninguno por defecto, pues ninguno tiene el atributo **selected**, pero según parece jquery elije el primero de todos modos a pesar que no tiene el **selected** puesto.

Prueba con esto para dejarlo a la escucha correctamente:

```js
// valor por defecto durante la carga del script   
var no_precio = $("#nuevoIdCliente>option:selected").attr("no_precio");
alert(no_precio);

// monitorización del evento change 
$("#nuevoIdCliente").on('change', function() {
    var no_precio = $("#nuevoIdCliente>option:selected").attr("no_precio");
    alert(no_precio);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select2" id="nuevoIdCliente" name="nuevoIdCliente">
<option no_precio="1" value="Pedro">Pedro</option>
<option no_precio="2" value="Marco">Marco</option>
<option no_precio="2" value="Erik">Erik</option>
</select>
```

donde lo que hacemos es usar el método **[on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)** para dejar a la escucha **siempre** al evento *change* de ese *select*. Y para el valor por defecto lo sacamos fuera de ese método para que se asigne durante la carga inicial del script.